# My Rails server is not running

Tags: cmd

My Rails server was working fine but now all of a sudden it says that in the cmd and it does not start. I can not connect to localhost:3000.Any ideas why this is happening???

```
 C:\Users\Monika\College\Mary\RailsProject\reviewapp>rails s
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Call with -d to detach
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
            SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
            This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
            provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
            cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
            future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

            Called from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/action
    pack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initi
    alize'.

    Exiting
    C:/Users/Monika/College/Mary/RailsProject/reviewapp/config/routes.rb:18:in `bloc
    k in <top (required)>': undefined method `recourses' for #<ActionDispatch::Routi
    ng::Mapper:0x47577a8> (NoMethodError)
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
    .1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:272:in `instance_exec'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
    .1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:272:in `eval_block'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
    .1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:249:in `draw'
            from C:/Users/Monika/College/Mary/RailsProject/reviewapp/config/routes.r
    b:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
    3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
    3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
    3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
    3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
    3.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
    3.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
            from C:2:in `rescue in execute_if_updated'
            from C:in `execute_if_updated'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
            from C:/Users/Monika/College/Mary/RailsProject/reviewapp/config/environm
    ent.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Users/Monika/College/Mary/RailsProject/reviewapp/config.ru:3:in
    `require'
            from C:/Users/Monika/College/Mary/RailsProject/reviewapp/config.ru:3:in
    `block in <main>'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
    /rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
    /rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
            from C:/Users/Monika/College/Mary/RailsProject/reviewapp/config.ru:in `n
    ew'
            from C:/Users/Monika/College/Mary/RailsProject/reviewapp/config.ru:in `<
    main>'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
    /rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
    /rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
    /rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1z
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
    /rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
    /rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
    /lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
            from script/rails:6:in `require'
            from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

I ran some sort of rake ... I do not remember what exactly it was and think that may be the cause.

Comment: What does the ```reviewapp/config/routes.rb``` file look like?

Comment: Reviewapp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "sessions/new"

  get "sessions/create"

  get "sessions/destroy"

  get "pages/about"

  resources :reviews

  resources :products

  resources :customers

  resources :categories
  
  recourses :sessions
  
 match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new'
 match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

Comment: Sorry I can not answer my question because I do not have higher reputation so I cant post a better layout ...

Comment: You should be able to edit your questions if you want to add some information. Only post actual answers as an answer (for example if you solve the problem yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your routes, change:

```
recourses :sessions
```

to:

```
resources :sessions
```

Comment: I was staring at that for so long and cant believe I did not see it .... but unfortunately it is still not letting me connect to the server after I run rails s =[

Comment: I fixed it was a syntax error. Thank you so much. I didnt think it is something as simple as that ... I feel a bit stupid but I am only learning,which I am sorry about. Thanks

Comment: No worries, these things can be hard to spot. Good luck with learning this awesome framework :)